# Error when I read file on JSP page using PC remote

Tags: java, string, web-services, jsp, fileinputstream

I have a question:

I have this jsp client that requires the entry of a string that indicates the path of a file:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="action.jsp" method="post">
            Enter NameFile (Excel):<input type="text" name="filename"/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, When I click on "Submit", I have this page JSP:

```
<%@page import="java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileInputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page contentType="text/plain" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page Action</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <%-- start web service invocation --%><hr/>
    <%
    String filename = request.getParameter("filename");

    File file = new File (filename);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
        bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); //no doubt here is 0
    }

    byte[] bi = bos.toByteArray();
    try {
    ws.MyWS_Service service = new ws.MyWS_Service();
    ws.MyWS port = service.getMyWSPort();
     // TODO initialize WS operation arguments here
    byte[] inputFile = bi;
    // TODO process result here
    java.lang.String result = port.mywsmethod(inputFile);
    out.println(result);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    // TODO handle custom exceptions here
    }
    %>
    <%-- end web service invocation --%><hr/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, if I insert

> C:\prova.xls

in a PC remote, I get this error:

```
07-Oct-2014 08:55:10.194 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-41] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/myWS_Client] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /action1.jsp at line 27

25: 
26:     File file = new File (filename);
27:     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
28:     ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


Stacktrace:] with root cause
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\prova.xls (Impossibile trovare il file specificato)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.jsp.action1_005f1_jsp._jspService(action1_005f1_jsp.java:96)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:335)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:534)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2381)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2370)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Why I get this error? What am I wrong? I tried to write this path with "//", "\", "\" and "/" but I get always the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP is a server side process.  The file name and path that you enter in HTML / Javascript may not exist on the server.

Consider using a file upload to upload the file to the server where the JSP can action it.

Also consider using servlet technology and using code in JSP is frowned upon.

Comment: ok... consider that I want to upload a file, convert it to array byte and send to my Web Service... how can I do it?

Comment: I saw this docs... but I don't want upload the file in a destination on the server... I want to load a file, convert and send the array byte only

Comment: what is the difference between a file and the collection of its individual bytes?

Comment: the difference is that I cannot save the file on the server, but, I send individual bytes and elaborate it on the server without save it. I don't want to save nothing on the server

Comment: As per the link I gave you, the file does not need to be saved on the server, simply use the inputstream directly `final Part filePart = request.getPart("file");`  `filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();`